# How do I use /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, webserver, resolv.conf

I need help using the file /etc/resolv.conf

What are `nameserver`, `domain` and `search`?

How can I prevent the file from resetting?

What is networkmanager?

I'm trying to set up a website

My version of Ubuntu Server is 16.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

For general information about configuring the libc resolver, read the manpage resolv.conf(5). For Ubuntu-specific aspects, read the manpage resolvconf(8) and Stéphane Graber's blog post: https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/